# Finding the first row in a colomn where a criteria is met (value is higher than x) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

In Python, (+Numpy or Pandas?)

I'm looking for a way to find the first row where a value is higher than X (lets say **9**).

Comment: Can you provide the exact form of the input? And a example of what you've tried so far would be fair also.

Comment: @BenjaminToueg, yes, I realise it would be fair to tell what I tried, Honestly, I'm very new to programming, and i searched the web for a whole evening, and found lots of filtering options, but I found nothing on how to find the first row.
Input is like this {"values":[[3,1],[2,10],[5,5]]}

Comment: @Frtschaal how did you get to the second set of data from the first set? i mean, there is no 50 in the first set, and where is the row `9, 10, 16*`?

Comment: The source has only 2 columns. The 3rd column should be created by adding, but this seems doable.

Comment: @ behzad.nouri, oops, I changed the numbers a bit to get the point across, but messed up, fixed it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the `[2,10,5]` line comes from. But the general idea is something like...

```
data = {'values':[[1,10,1],[3,1,3],[4,3,5],[6,6,7],[7,10,8],[7,10,16],[14,5,22],[18,1,30]]}
x = 9
for i,row in enumerate(data['values']):
    if row[2]>x:
        rows = data['values'][max(0,i-4):i]
        break

assert rows == [[3,1,3],[4,3,5],[6,6,7],[7,10,8]]

# etc...
y = 8
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
    if row[1]>y:
        ans = rows[i][0]
        break

# etc...
assert ans == 7
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But do you happen to know a way to speed it up? Numpy?